# Scrapy FormRequest not do the post request

Tags: scrapy

I don't want this

`return [FormRequest.from_response(response,`

Because the login form not have the `<form>` tag

So I tried:

```
return scrapy.FormRequest(url="...",
                    formdata={},
                    callback=self.after_post)


return [FormRequest(url="...",
                    formdata={},
                    callback=self.after_post)]


return scrapy.http.Request(url="...",
            method='POST',
            headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'},
            body=json.dumps(postData),
            callback=self.after_post)
```

(Ref: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-to-send-data-via-http-post)

But seem that scrapy not do the POST request and the code not goto the `after_post`

`2020-04-07 10:43:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)`

Can anyone tell me if I did something wrong here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I writed the post in another function

So when do this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    self.do_post()
```

(not work)

And

```
def parse(self, response):
   return self.do_post()
```

(This will work)

Not sure why the `return` caused the problem.

(Question closed)